# Hypothesis testing for monthly data of several groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons

I have 5 sensors and they count number of cars pass through that sensor each day. I have gathered monthly data for all sensors.(i.e. summing each day's data. Now I want to test whether distribution of cars passing through these sensors differ. I was planning to conduct one-way ANOVA but is it right? Is there a better alternative for that? Lastly how can I tackle multiple testing problem. I was considering Bonferroni correction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific in what kind of differences you are looking for? There are multiple ways to test for "different", and the appropriate method depends on the specific goal

Comment: Also, a plot of the distributions would be helpful - both to potential answerers and probably for you to reason also :)

Comment: @JonNordby I want to test whether distribution of how many cars pass through these sensors differ? so whether these samples originate from same distribution.